# Improving an inefficient query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having an issue where my app is timing out because the query is taking too long. I'm using the free tier of Heroku so I'm not exactly getting a priority on speed and therefore I'm getting timeouts which I don't see locally. I was hoping someone could see an issue with my query that would allow me to speed things up.

My query looks like this:

```
  def index
    # file = File.read('app\controllers\recipe.csv')
    clear_database
    file = get_file
    recipe_array = file.split("\n")
    dbUser = User.find_by(id: 999999999)
    recipe_array.each do |recipe|
      # I'm saving here becuase I need the ID later
      dbRecipe = dbUser.recipes.create

      recipe = recipe.split(",")
      url_index = recipe.length - 1
      img_url_index = recipe.length - 2
      recipe.each_with_index do |item, index|
        if index == 0
          dbRecipe.name = item.strip.downcase
          dbRecipe.save
        elsif index == url_index
          dbRecipe.url = item
          dbRecipe.save
        elsif index == img_url_index
          dbRecipe.img_url = item
          dbRecipe.save
        elsif index.odd?
          count = item
          food = recipe[index + 1]
          dbIngredient = Ingredient.new
          dbFood = Food.find_by_name(food)
          if dbFood.nil?
            dbFood = Food.new
            dbFood.name = food.strip.downcase
            dbFood.save
          end

          # populate ingredient
          dbIngredient.unit_type = item.split(" ").last
          dbIngredient.quantity = item.split(" ").first
          # I'm saving so much above because I need the id's
          dbIngredient.recipe_id = dbRecipe.id
          dbIngredient.food_id = dbFood.id
          dbIngredient.save
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

My data is made up of recipes that are stored on in a CSV file. There are about 300 rows that look like this:

```
"Sirloin Steak with Blue Cheese Compound Butter,0.6 oz, Butter,2 count, Garlic Cloves,2 count, Green Onions,12 oz, Fingerling Potatoes,8 oz, Green Beans,12 oz, Sirloin Steaks,1 oz, Blue Cheese,https://homechef.imgix.net/https%3A%2F%2Fasset.homechef.com%2Fuploads%2Fmeal%2Fplated%2F2543%2F2543SirloinSteakwithBlueCheeseCompoundButterReshoot2__1_of_1_-b04048840f58000cef80b38fc3f77856-b04048840f58000cef80b38fc3f77856.jpg?ixlib=rails-1.1.0&w=425&auto=format&s=eeba60ce35bcee4938a11286cbea0203,https://www.homechef.com/meals/sirloin-steak-with-blue-cheese-compound-butter
Teriyaki Ginger-Glazed Salmon,1 Tbsp, Chopped Ginger,2 count, Garlic Cloves,2 count, Green Onions,8 oz, Carrot,2 count, Heads of Baby Bok Choy,1 count, Red Fresno Chile,2 oz, Teriyaki Glaze,12 oz, Salmon Fillets,https://homechef.imgix.net/https%3A%2F%2Fasset.homechef.com%2Fuploads%2Fmeal%2Fplated%2F3429%2F3429TeriyakiGinger-GlazedSalmonReshoot3__1_of_1_-73adcd6ad23cc72b28fdba85387fa18a-73adcd6ad23cc72b28fdba85387fa18a.jpg?ixlib=rails-1.1.0&w=425&auto=format&s=9e6b37380203ec5a58a5ddb906b5ae8b,https://www.homechef.com/meals/teriyaki-ginger-glazed-salmon
Al Pastor Pork Flautas,1 count, Shallot,1 count, Lime,3 oz, Pineapple Chunks,1 oz, Queso Fresco,12 oz, Ground Pork,1 tsp, Chipotle Seasoning,6 count, Small Flour Tortillas,0.5 oz, Baby Arugula,1 oz, Sour Cream,10 oz, Ground Beef,https://homechef.imgix.net/https%3A%2F%2Fasset.homechef.com%2Fuploads%2Fmeal%2Fplated%2F4290%2F4290AlPastorPorkFlautasFinal2__1_of_1_-4e7fe04ac157a463b4d93eb57e9b93f9-4e7fe04ac157a463b4d93eb57e9b93f9.jpg?ixlib=rails-1.1.0&w=425&auto=format&s=de2e2403d7261f2697567faf5f477359,https://www.homechef.com/meals/al-pastor-pork-flautas
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't actually a query, it's a whole bunch of other things.  You are parsing a file and writing to the database based on the contents of that file. Also, if all you are doing is seeding the DB, there is no reason to involve the app or the browser at all.  This task would be better accomplished through a rake task or from the rails console.  You can avoid database timeout by breaking the actions into separate pieces, eg

- load the file into memory
- for each line of the file, write to the database and save the record

In any case you should take this seeding of the DB out of the app entirely.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to do too much within a single http request/response cycle. For every row in your CSV you're doing a sql `INSERT` (with `dbUser.recipes.create`), an `UPDATE` (with `dbRecipe.save`), as well as a `SELECT` (with `Food.find_by_name(food)`).

Even if you make some optimizations, are you sure that the CSV will only have ~300 rows for the life of your app? And even if the answer is yes, generally speaking it is good practice to respond to a user action as quickly as possible instead of having them watch their browser wait for a response.

So, I recommend you rethink your approach. If a single action has to execute a lot of sql commands, think of ways to have the task run asynchronously. This is what tools like `ActiveJob` (https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) and sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/) were designed for.

For example, design your app in such a way that a user clicks some button for uploading the CSV and respond with: "Thanks for your submission, we're working on it!". The user could always come back and check the status of the file being processed or refresh the screen. Or you could get more sophisticated and automate status checks with AJAX polling or bi-directional communication via websockets. The Railsy way to do this would be with `ActionCable` (https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_cable_overview.html).

Comment: I'm using this as a way to seed my prod database from a CSV the is produced by a webscraper. It only needs to happen once in blue moon as I'm developing the app and the page is only accessible to me. After I finish development I will no longer use this method.

Comment: You have to use database seed it won't show you timeout as it runs in the background on command rails db:seed

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import) gem - main idea of which is loading many records by one query.

You must specify column names as array:

```rb
column_names = [:name, :quantity, :unit_type, :food_id]
```

Next you must load data from csv in same order:

```rb
row_values = [
  ["Sirloin Steak with Blue Cheese Compound Butter", 1, "Butter", 2],
  ["Something else", 2, "else", 32],
  ...
]
```

and import:

```rb
DbIngredient.import(column_names, row_values)
```